# Printing stack to console while popping elements throws exception non-deterministically

Tags: java, eclipse, concurrency, stack

I was just writing a remarkably simply "Stack" class in Java on the eclipse Juno IDE that has 2 operations - push and pop. One check I have in the pop() method is to see if the stack is empty; if so, I throw a NoSuchElementException. Therefore, if I push 1,2,3,4,5 sequentially and then pop elements five times, I expect to see 5,4,3,2,1 printed out in that order. But after adding five elements, if i deliberately try to pop the stack SIX times, I would expect 5,4,3,2,1, and then a NoSuchElementException.

What's happening in my case is that console prints out the NoSuchElementException haphazardly (i.e. not always after printing out 5,4,3,2,1; sometimes it prints out:

```
stack pop: 5
stack pop: 4
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: Stack Underflow
stack pop: 3
stack pop: 2
stack pop: 1
    at Stack.pop(Stack.java:29)
    at Stack.main(Stack.java:47)
```

and sometimes it prints out:

```
Exception in thread "main" stack pop: 5
stack pop: 4
stack pop: 3
stack pop: 2
stack pop: 1
java.util.NoSuchElementException: Stack Underflow
    at Stack.pop(Stack.java:29)
    at Stack.main(Stack.java:47)
```

My goal is to understand what governs this behavior. Since I'm using print statements (and not a logger which might have a queue-like implementation underneath) I would expect to see the statements in order, but I suspect that there's some concurrency at play here. Below is my code:

import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

```
public class Stack {

    private Node first;
    private int size;

    private class Node{
       Node next;
       int value;
    }

    public Stack(){
       size=0;
       first=null;
    }

    public void push(int x){        
        Node previousFirst = first;
        first = new Node();
        first.value = x;
        first.next = previousFirst;
        size++;
    }

    public int pop(){
        if(first == null){
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Stack Underflow");
        }       
        int poppedNodeVal = first.value;
        first = first.next;
        size--;
        return poppedNodeVal;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack stack1 = new Stack();
        stack1.push(1);
        stack1.push(2);
        stack1.push(3);
        stack1.push(4);
        stack1.push(5); 
        for(int i=5; i>=0;i--){
            System.out.println("stack pop: " + stack1.pop());
        }
    }

}
```

Any thoughts on how to reliably print this out and more importantly, what could be causing this non-deterministic printing of the exception in the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exception is not catched so it stops program execution. The issue is probably

a) You are inserting 5 elements and extracting 6, change your loop to

```
 for(int i = 5; i >0; i--)
```

b) The exception is thrown after the `System.out.println` for all 5 elements has been executed (otherwise those lines would not print at all, since the program exits). But part of the contents have still not yet printed to console (it has a buffer). When the exception breaks in, it print to `System.err` (a different buffer), since in your case both `System.out` and `System.err` end in the console, you get the mixed contents.

Wrap your `for`  in a `try/catch` block and intercept the exception. Print a message to `System.out` informing of it. You will see that it appears before printing the last element.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation regarding the streams being different and how the out stream has a buffer. It makes complete sense why they are printing "mixed" contents. However, I did try your suggestion of wrapping the for-loop into a try/catch block and noticed something interesting. If my catch-block has the following: System.out.println("Sorry! " + e.getMessage()) -> things work fine. But the moment I add a e.printStackTrace() things are miserably haphazard again. You reckon it's the same problem regarding the difference in stream-types?

Comment: Yes. Check the javadoc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace(). It states that it prints to `stderr`. You can use a different method (`printStackTrace(System.out)`) to use the standard output.

Comment: This is really useful; I can now reliably print out a stackTrace in a reliable order by piping it to System.out consistently. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

this is because the System.err and the System.out are not the same stream, sometimes can happen that they are not synchronized.
System.err is for exception, System.out is what you use.

maybe you want to try something like this:

```
System.setErr(System.out);
```

Thiw will route the standard System.err to the System.out
now you should have the correct 5,4,3,2,1, Exception flow.

Obviously if the two stream are separated there is a reason, so you can do what I told you but be careful to do it just during testing (like in jUnit)

Comment: This was very enlightening; I just always assumed that these streams were synchronized but the moment I incorporated your suggestion I see things working just as expected. Just out of curiosity, are there any cases where routing the error stream into the out stream is particularly bad practice?

Comment: I don't use default streams too much, I won't tell you something I am not certain, of course in my opinion System.out is black and System.err is red, if you use an ide like eclipse you will understand me ;)

Comment: When running from a command line, (Linux shell, Windows command prompt, Mac terminal) you can redirect output and error separately. If you use the suggestion, these will not function correctly as everything is being written to `out` and nothing is being written to `err`. Lumping them together will annoy the command line users, as you've taken away the ability to manage them independently.

Comment: That's an important perspective that slipped my mind as I don't frequently run my java programs via the terminal. The neatest thing to do I guess would be catch the exception in the for-loop, and print to err within the catch block.

Answer (score 2):

Your messages are using `System.out` but the exceptions are printed on `System.err`. The Eclipse console does not synchronize these two streams so they can appear on the console out of order. Try outputing your messages to `System.err` and they should be in order.